# Create Pandas DataFrame column with weight if value in 1 column is between values in 2 other columns

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I'm unable to add a weight (int) to a new Pandas DataFrame column if a value in one column is between two values in other columns. I'm able to create the column with a True/False value (or a 0/1 value if I use astype), however.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [3,6,4]})
df

   a  b  c
0  1  4  3
1  2  5  6
2  3  6  4
```

> This works:

```
df['between_bool'] = df['c'].between(df['a'], df['b'])
df

   a  b  c between_bool
0  1  4  3         True     # 3 is between 1 and 4
1  2  5  6        False     # 6 is NOT between 2 and 5
2  3  6  4         True     # 4 is between 3 and 6
```

> However, this does NOT work:

```
df['between_int'] = df['c'].apply(lambda x: 2 if df['c'].between(df['a'], df['b']) else 0)
```

> The code above generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\envs\PortfolioManager\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-14-0aa1e7cfd5c2>", line 1, in <module>
    df['between_int'] = df['c'].apply(lambda x: 2 if df['c'].between(df['a'], df['b']) else 0)
  File "C:\Python36\envs\PortfolioManager\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2294, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1207, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:66124)
  File "<ipython-input-14-0aa1e7cfd5c2>", line 1, in <lambda>
```

> The desired output is:

```
   a  b  c between_int
0  1  4  3           2      # 3 is between 1 and 4
1  2  5  6           0      # 6 is NOT between 2 and 5
2  3  6  4           2      # 4 is between 3 and 6
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand you correctly, but if you just want to add the fixed weight 2 on this condition, one option is to do the following:

```
import numpy as np
df['between_int'] = np.where(df['c'].between(df['a'], df['b']), 2, 0)
```

Alternatively you could do the following if you do not want to import numpy:

```
df['between_int'] = 0
df.loc[df['c'].between(df['a'], df['b']), 'between_int'] = 2
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you wanted to do at first with `apply` was:

```
df['between_int'] = df.apply(lambda x: 2 if x['c'] in range(x['a'], x['b']) else 0, axis=1)
```

See the difference with yours:

1. `apply` on the dataframe `df` not the serie `df['c']`
2. get the value you want to check by `x['c']` not `df['c']` as your lambda is function of x
3. because I changed `df['c']` to `x['c']` I can't use `between` anymore but `in range`
4. for both bounds, call them by `x['a']` and `x['b']`, for the same reason than point 2
5. Finally, don't forget `axis=1` as now `apply` is on a dataframe

Anyway, the solutions of swebbo work perfectly!